Drone YAML variable expansion for image plugin/ecr under settings tag
When trying to access either of -
pipeline environment variable or step environment variable or settings environment variable, I am not able to use it in my docer ecr image to read either of these environment variable to set up a tag,
However they all show up under the commands if i run printenv, but just do not work under tags in setting
PIPELINE VAR
        - $GLOBAL_ENV_VAR1 #Error parsing reference: "987654321012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/org/application-name:$GLOBAL_ENV_VAR1" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
        - $${GLOBAL_ENV_VAR1} #Error parsing reference: "987654321012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/org/application-name:${GLOBAL_ENV_VAR1}" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
        - ${GLOBAL_ENV_VAR1} #Error parsing reference: "987654321012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/org/application-name:" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format

SETTING ENV VAR
        - $PLUGIN_STEP_ENV_VAR_SETTING # Error parsing reference: "987654321012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/org/application-name:$PLUGIN_STEP_ENV_VAR_SETTING" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
        - $${PLUGIN_STEP_ENV_VAR_SETTING} #Error parsing reference: "987654321012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/org/application-name:${PLUGIN_STEP_ENV_VAR_SETTING}" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
        - ${PLUGIN_STEP_ENV_VAR_SETTING} # Error parsing reference: "987654321012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/org/application-name:" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format

ENV VAR
        - $STEP_ENV_VAR #Error parsing reference: "987654321012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/org/application-name:$STEP_ENV_VAR" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
        - ${STEP_ENV_VAR} #Error parsing reference: "987654321012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/org/application-name:" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
        - $${STEP_ENV_VAR} Error parsing reference: "987654321012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/org/application-name:${STEP_ENV_VAR}" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format

Please help.
Regards.
I expect
settings:
tags:
-$ENV_VAR
to work.
